# Is it possible to run InstrumentationTestRunner programmatically?

Tags: android, testing

Is it possible to invoke a InstrumentationTestRunner programmatically from application A to run all tests in application B?

And is it possible to fetch the results?

Answer (score 3):

The post [Android: Running tests from code](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-testing-running-tests-from-code.html) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: do you know if its also possible to fetch the results?

Comment: Results are in logcat. If this was the answer you were looking for, please accept it.

Comment: I want the test results in application A so that i can show them in something like a dashboard.

Comment: do you know howto fetch the results in the application?

Comment: Once you start the instrumentation the Activity that started it is finished, so it's not simple to get the results back. Probably creating a new test runner that saves the results somewhere could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming application A is a non-android applicaiton here right? So If application A was a bash script you could do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
adb shell am instrument -w
```

Put that in a script file, and then you can just run that script every time you want to run your tests.